# SQL: Get all rows with matching string, how can I improve performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, database-design

I'm building a little application that allows users to create comments on webpages. The way it works is that you send the `origin` with the comment you want to add to a page, then you fetch all the comments for a page by querying `WHERE origin LIKE 'https://somesite.com/page-1'`.

`id` is unique, but `origin` obviously isn't, as there might be multiple comments for a specific page.

```
 table_name | column_name |          data_type
------------+-------------+-----------------------------
 Comment    | id          | text
 Comment    | origin      | text
 Comment    | body        | text
```

So far this has worked pretty well, but the database is still relatively small. I don't see this scaling very well but I'm unsure of how it could be improved.

My initial thought was to create a different copy of the above table on the fly for each new site added, but that sounds like a nightmare to manage in case I needed to deploy changes to my schema.

How should I handle a situation like this? How should my database schema look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition:

```
WHERE origin LIKE 'https://somesite.com/page-1'
```

is equivalent to:

```
WHERE origin = 'https://somesite.com/page-1'
```

For equality, you can use a regular, B-tree index on `origin`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_comment_origin ON comment(origin);
```

For more complex comparisons using `LIKE`, you can use a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-intro.html), but that is not necessary for the example in your question.

Comment: Does creating a B-tree index and using `origin = ''` automatically make my queries perform better without any other changes?

Comment: @Eight: indexes are used automatically - if applicable and the Postgres query planner expects the query plan using the index in some fashion to be faster. That's typically the case for your example.